# Use setup.py to install remote tar dependency

Tags: python, setup.py

Using `pip`, you can easily install a package in tar form as in:

`pip install https://path/to/respository/ending/with/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz`

However, I can't seem to get `python setup.py install` to find this same remote repository.

In `setup.py`, I have:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='blah',
      version='0.1.0',
      description='A library',
      install_requires=[
           'en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz'
      ],
      dependency_links=[
            'https://path/to/respository/ending/with/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz'
      ],
      packages=['blah'])
```

My error message is:

> No local packages or working download links found for en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz
>   error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz')

How can I accomplish the same with setup.py that I can with pip?

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out. This tip from the spacy docs:

https://spacy.io/usage/models#production

You need to add `#egg=en_core_web_sm` to the end of the dependency_link. Final file looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='blah',
      version='0.1.0',
      description='A library',
      install_requires=[
           'en-core-web-sm'
      ],
      dependency_links=[
            'https://path/to/respository/ending/with/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0/en_core_web_sm-2.1.0.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_sm'
      ],
      packages=['blah'])
```

Comment: This doesn't work with en-core-web-lg with defpedency_links = ["https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_lg"] whereas pip install ["https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5/en_core_web_lg-2.2.5.tar.gz#egg=en_core_web_lg"] works. So not a working solution now. May be they have changed something